# How do i check if input is a date

Tags: python, function

I want to define a function that will check if input is a date. If input is not a date i want it to say: sorry try again and if it is a date i need a program to stop. I tried many things but none of them worked and I don't have codes of what I tried because I deleted the function.

Comment: As an aside, why did you delete the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `datetime` library:

```
import datetime

def validate(date_text):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d')
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
```

than validate like that:

```
validate('2015-08-18')
```

Comment: It shouldn't be like that it should be so i could add that function to the another variable where user has to input a date and that should check for him

Comment: I gave you the idea, and you should do the rest. it's just `user_input = raw_input(); try:  validate(user_input) ...`.

Comment: one more thing, how can i make it repeat it self if input is not a date.

Comment: use a loop: `is_date=False; while(not is_date): try: v=raw_input(); validate(v);  is_date = True ; except: pass`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dateutil` module and see if you can convert the input if not print `try again`

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
def validate_string(inp_string):
    try:
        parse(inp_string)
        print "yes"
    except :
        print "Wrong try again"
validate_string("asd")
```

**output:**

```
validate_string("asd")
Wrong try again
validate_string('2015-01-1')
yes
```